# How can I remove cURL error in GAE google appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I'm facing this error in php file `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()` when I upload my file on Google appengine gae then I get this error:

I'm trying this cURL in PHP

```
function getpage($url)
{
// fetch data
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; ASUS_T00J Build/LRX21V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)      Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36');

$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
//return preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', ' ', $data);
return $data;
}
```

The error is found on this `line $curl = curl_init();`

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install curl.

Windows:
Go to your php.ini file and remove the ; mark from the beginning of the following line:

`;extension=php_curl.dll`

Ubuntu:
ubuntu 13.0 and above, simply use the debundled package. In a terminal type the following to install it and do not forgot to restart server.

`sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

On GAE:

**To Enable cURL_lite**

1. Add the directive `google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"` to your php.ini file.

Caveats

- cURL_lite is only allowed to make calls to HTTP or HTTPS clients
- cURL_lite didn’t work on my local development server without tweaking runtime to php55, but it works for php in production
- cURL_lite doesn’t require application to have billing enabled

**To Enable cURL**

1. Change your runtime setting in your app.yaml from php to php55.
2. Add the directive extension = “curl.so” to your php.ini file.

Caveats

- cURL is only available in App Engine’s PHP 5.5 implementation
- cURL can only be used by applications that have billing enabled
- cURL is limited by the restrictions of App Engine’s sockets but include:

  - Limited from targeting Google domains
  - May be reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity

Comment: but i have not any php.ini file in my folder

Comment: The php.ini is your Main configuration File. You start php with this file.
(Infos: https://secure.php.net/manual/de/configuration.file.php)
Are you using Windows, or Linux, Unix Maschine?

Comment: windows but i'm try to set for Google gae app engine

Comment: On windows the php.ini is located in the root from your PHP Folder.

You need to edit the File to allow/load the Curl extension.
Without you can not use curl.

Comment: i have app.yaml file only

Comment: I Updated my answer for gae